# Help with a particular solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the solution of the following differential equation:
\begin{equation*}
x''(t)+\omega^2x(t)=a[K_1\cos(\omega t)+K_2\sin(\omega t)]+b[-K_1\omega\sin(\omega t)+K_2\omega\cos(wt)]
\end{equation*}
where $\omega>0$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $K_1,K_2>0$. I have calculated the solution of the homogenous equation, but I don't know what particular solution of the ODE I have to take. Any help?

Comment: Try $x(t)=A\cos\omega t+B\sin\omega t$, substitute and compare the two sides.

Comment: I mean that I don't know a particular solution of the global equation, not the homogenous one.

Comment: Have you tried the variation of parameter method to find a particular solution, i.e. $x_p(t) = A(t)\cos \omega t + B(t)\sin \omega t$?

Comment: yes, but I don't know really good

Comment: In the resonance case like here you have to try $x(t)=t(A\cos ωt+B\sin ωt)$, where $A,B$ are constants.

Comment: Thanks!! I have the solution now

Answer (score 0):

Using Rem's idea, I have arrived to this system:
\begin{equation*}
A''(t)+2B'(t)\omega=aK_1+bK_2\omega
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
B''(t)-2A'(t)\omega=aK_2-bK_1\omega
\end{equation*}
How can I find $A(t)$ and $B(t)$?

Comment: If you set them linear, then the second derivatives fall away and the integration confirms a linear solution.